# fatal error for pushing file to github

Tags: git, github

I would like to transfer a local repo to another repo already located in github.
I did :
git clone http:xxxxxx --> files transfered
At the repo, i created a folder with one file

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "xxx"
$ git push (or git push origin master)
```

Here is the message on my terminal :
[image]

Could you help me ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

First, *Pull* `master` branch, then Push to `master` cause remote `master` is ahead of local.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```